# how Set autolayout for multiple dynamic buttons and labells in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I am creating 83 dynamic buttons in my app and setting labels for that. Now, I want to set auto layout for the same. How can I set auto layout dynamically for this?

This is the code I implemented for creating buttons and labels dynamically:

```
-(void)DynamicButton
{
    //Reading Data From database
    NSMutableArray *objectName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    self.databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SMS.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:self.databasePath];
    [database setLogsErrors:TRUE];
    [database open];

    //FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM SMSCategory"];
    NSString *anQuery = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"SELECT *FROM SMSCategory"];

    FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:anQuery];

    while ([results next]) {
        SMSCat1 *cat = [[SMSCat1 alloc]init];
        cat.Id = [results stringForColumn:@"Id"];
        cat.Name = [results stringForColumn:@"Name"];
        cat.IsActive = [results stringForColumn:@"IsActive"];
        [objectName addObject:cat];
    }
    [database close];


    //Adding dynamic buttons


    int yPossion = 150, xPossion = 44; int temp = 0;
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    for (int i = 0; i < [objectName count]; i++) {
        SMSCat1 *cat = [objectName objectAtIndex:i];

        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [aButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];


        //Label Dynamic Code

        UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [label setText:cat.Name];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
        label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

        [label sizeToFit];

        [label setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 44, 70, 60)];
        [scrollView addSubview:label];
        [aButton addSubview:label];





        [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [aButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xPossion, yPossion, 70, 60)];
        aButton.highlighted = YES;

        [scrollView addSubview:aButton];

        xPossion += aButton.frame.size.width + 35;
        temp++;
        if (temp == 3) {
            yPossion = aButton.frame.origin.y + aButton.frame.size.height + 20;
            temp = 0;
            xPossion = 44;
            yPossion += aButton.frame.size.width - 15;
            [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, yPossion - 50)];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to set auto layout for dynamic multiple  buttons

Answer (score 0):

When using auto layout for this you want to set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO`. This allows you to set the position of objects using your own constraints. When placing the objects using auto layout you don't really care about the frame. You want to place object relative to objects around it or its parent view. For example you can do something like this:

```
NSDictionary* views = @{@"label1":label1,@"button1":button};
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[label1]-(10)-[button1]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
  [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

this will set the two elements 10 pixels apart and center them vertically. I wont go through your code and change all of it to auto layout but you see in my example how to start laying out your objects with auto layout

Comment: but how to set for multiple dynamic buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

for (int i = 0;i<[list count];i++)

```
    id val=[list objectAtIndex:i];
    CGFloat val1=[val floatValue];
    UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0,107,40)];  
    newLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",list[i]];
    newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    newLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    newLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    newLabel.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    [self.view addSubview:newLabel];
    x=x+newLabel.frame.size.width;
```

Comment: Use for loop and set size using X.. Its working Fine.